# Slider control to select a range of data

Tags: graph, controls, ria, web-applications

[image: Slider Control]

Are there any RIA libraries/toolkits/frameworks that supports a control similar to the above?

I need a slider control to select a range of data.

Comment: I think this belongs on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [jQRangeSlider](http://ghusse.github.com/jQRangeSlider/).

Take a look at the [demo](http://ghusse.github.com/jQRangeSlider/demo.html)